# Kotlin, secondary constructor of a child class

Tags: syntax, kotlin

I try to call parent's second constructor like this

```
abstract class A(val i: Int) {
    constructor(c: C) : this(c.i)
}

class B() : A(0) {
    constructor(c: C) : super(c) // error is here
}

class C(val i: Int)
```

but it generates `Primary constructor call expected` error. How can the child class call the parent's secondary constructor?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to the [doc](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/classes.html):

> If the class has a primary constructor, **each secondary constructor
>   needs to delegate to the primary constructor**, either directly or
>   indirectly through another secondary constructor(s). Delegation to another constructor of the same class is done using the this keyword

You declare a primary constructor for `B` (i.e. `B()`), so the secondary constructor should call its primary constructor.

> How can the child class call the parent's secondary constructor?

If you want the secondary constructor to call the parent's secondary constructor, you should remove `B`'s primary constructor first.

```
abstract class A(val i: Int) {
    constructor(c: C) : this(c.i)
}

class B : A {
    constructor(c: C) : super(c)
}

class C(val i: Int)
```